# On npm Install I am getting "Unhandled rejection Error: Integrity check failed", but when I delete package-lock.json the error disappears

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a nodejs project versioned in a GIT repo. When I clone the project, the package-lock.json is included (as it should be) but when I execute "npm install" I get the error `Unhandled rejection Error: Integrity check failed`

**If I delete the package-lock.json everything works**

- node version: 8.14.0
- npm version: 6.5.0

Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.258.1",
    "localmodule": "file:../LocalModule/dist/localmodule-1.1.1.tgz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.3.2",
    "@types/sinon": "^5.0.1",
    "aws-sdk-mock": "^2.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "merge2": "^1.2.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "nps": "^5.9.2",
    "nps-utils": "^1.6.0",
    "sinon": "^5.0.10",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  }
```

Full error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Integrity check failed:from@0.1.7 extracted to /home/...
  Wanted: sha512-atI2DklW/phzBW2RyPznpbepvl1aRh7Y0XHfguqv...
   Found: sha512-9BeJ7UP5OY9cUDsNXlHaYL6Xqd1cARifioOEtF60...
    at checksumError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/content/write.js:157:13)
    at write (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/content/write.js:35:22)
    at putData (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/put.js:29:10)
    at Object.x.put (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js:28:37)
    at readFileAsync.then.data (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/file.js:38:28)
    at tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeback.js:42:21
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:90:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

Comment: Does this keep happening? Do you know which module is causing the problem?

Comment: It keeps happening. I don't know if any module is causing the issue. In other cases it seemed a npm bug with an specific version. But I have updated it the problem remains.

Comment: So what package is locked with that sha signature?

Comment: Basically it saves the sha checksum of the npm module - to make sure that the file hasn't been modified or corrupted. It's not a fatal condition, but I'm sure it will be annoying. It might also be a bad npm module. To see what it fixes, trying doing a `git diff` of the file to see what it changes

Comment: Ok. The package causing the problem is my local module. I have another project where I package the module always with the same name "localmodule-1.1.1.tgz". I understand that If the content of the package has changed but not the name nor the version, npm realizes that the package I am trying to install doesn't match the previous installed (looking at package-lock.json). This makes sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package causing the problem is my local module. I have another project where I package the module always with the same name "localmodule-1.1.1.tgz". 
The checksum of this module is stored in the package-lock.json.
When I change the content of the module, but not the name, npm detects that I am trying to install the same module but the checksum doesn't match.

Answer (score 7):

had a same issue today and landed on this page. the above thing doesn't worked for me but after awhile fixed it by doing small work..hence posting it ..might be helpful to others.

just delete "package-lock.json" file and do npm install... :)

Answer (score 5):

Try `npm cache verify` or `npm cache --force clean`. Then try `npm install`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To add to OP's answer, the error for me was a client produced private npm package that I first had to re-install with `npm i <path to client package>`. After re-install, I was able to run `npm i` and update all other packages successfully.